# Automated tool for VLOOK UP

Tags: vba, automation, vlookup

I need to perform many VLookup in a set of excel files, and for that I built a tool that can make automated VLookup from a file to another but I need to be make it scalable and adaptable.

For that, I want to input in some cells of the tool (which is an Excel file) the parameters for the VLookup:

- Position of Key Column
- Position of "Returned Value" Column
- Number of Columns in the range

Do you know how to change my tool in order for it to include these entry parameters ?

a sample of the code here:

```
For myrow = 3 To lastrow
    Range("b" & myrow).FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], Input!C[-1]:C[2],2,FALSE)"
Next myrow
```

Comment: `"I want to input in some cells of the tool (which is an Excel file) the parameters for the VLookup"` I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this?

Comment: It means : in the cell D4, input the position of  Key Column , in cell D5 input the Position of "Returned Value" Column ... thanks @Marcucciboy2

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I can send you the tool if you want, but I didn't figure how to attach the excel file to this Post... :(

Comment: You're better off not attaching anything - I know I dont click on external links and if someone wants to reference this in the future link rot is a serious problem :)

Comment: ok @Marcucciboy2, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well versed in `R1C1` notation, but if you were using regular `.Formula` notation:

The following code assumes that `A1` = Key column, `A2` = Returned value column, `A3` = Number of columns in the range (which is really just your return column).

`lastrow = 10` just for the example

Also note - you must be missing a field... since you should have 4 variables - key column for first parameter, 2 column letters for second parameter, and the number of columns for 3rd parameter.

```
Sub Test()

lastrow = 10

For myrow = 3 To lastrow

    'Range("B" & myrow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Range("A1").Value & myrow & ",Input!$" & Range("A1").Value & ":$" & Range("A2").Value & "," & Range("A3").Value & ",FALSE)"
    Debug.Print "=VLOOKUP(" & Range("A1").Value & myrow & ",Input!$" & Range("A1").Value & ":$" & Range("A2").Value & "," & Range("A3").Value & ",FALSE)"

Next myrow

End Sub
```

Values on `ActiveSheet`:

[image: img1]

Immediate window returns:

[image: img2]